# Getting SQL Server timeout exception even with command timeout set to 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have set the command timeout to 0 as per the documentation in SQL Server. I'm indexing a large table, and still get an exception "Execution timeout expired".  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The server is responding as I watch it though the SQL Server Monitor.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
private void ExecuteQuery(string qStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
    {
        cnx.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qStr, cnx))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the connection string
`Data Source='tcp:aplace.database.windows.net,1433';Initial Catalog='SQL-Dev';User Id='user@place';Password='password';Connection Timeout=360`

Why am I getting a execution timeout? I have the connection timeout set to 7200 seconds, also. I am indexing a 31 million rows table on one column.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're creating the index through this SqlCommand?  If so, is it taking 2+ hours to build the index?

Comment: No, it's not.  I was just informing you about that limit.  It fails very quickly with the message above.

Comment: Is "very quickly" in the neighborhood of 30 seconds?

Comment: Actually, it is very close to 30 seconds.  I thought the CommandTimeout = 0 overrode that!

Comment: It generally should.  Can you post your connection string?

Comment: Data Source='tcp:aplace.database.windows.net,1433';Initial Catalog='SQL-Dev';User Id='user@place';Password='password';Connection Timeout=360

Comment: That's what I normally have for connection timeout.  I upped it to 7200 for these tests.

Comment: That looks fine.  What is the Type of the exception you're getting?  Is it `SqlException`?

Comment: I trap it with an Exception.  The message above is what I see.  Exception, Execution timeout expired.  I'm trying to run it again, to check that more carefully, but now seems to be finishing the indexing in about 5 mins.

Comment: Don't mismatch Connection timeout and command timeout!  Please post the entire exception.

Comment: Can you put 0 for connection timeout?

Comment: Can’t get exact exception as it won’t fail again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, connection timeout and command timeout are not the same thing. Make sure you understand the difference and are using them correctly.

Second, if this is from a web page, you also need to consider timeout values relating to the web server, etc.

Third, to verify that it is in fact a timeout issue, execute your index statement in SSMS and find out how long it takes. Since the actual indexing takes place on the SQL server no matter where it is called from, the indexing time should be roughly equal whether running from SSMS or your application.

Comment: Not web. Works sometimes. What is timing out if you issue C# sql query to index a column on the sever?  It should do the index and return. How can you know how long it takes the first time you do it?

Comment: You should run the query in SQL Server Management Server (formerly called Query Analyzer). This will tell you how long it takes. Is that the full text of the error message? If not, post the full text, including any error numbers, etc. If there is a stack trace, post that as well.